# CRC-64 for an SHA256 hach

Tags: crc, sha256

hiii,
I have a question , if i calculate a crc for an sha256 hash to get a char with 64bits, Will I have a collision ? it's secure for reverse function ? 
thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IANAC.

I don't really understand what you mean by "Will I have a collision" - 64 bits can of course never represent 256 bits so yes, very very many of your possible sha256 hashes can collapse to the same 64 bit CRC.

If you just want a shorter value for your hash, I'd suggest folding instead, for example by xor:ing every consecutive byte in your hash with each other.
Or by xor:ing the first half of your 256 bit string with the second half to yield a 128 bit value, and then xor:ing that result's first half with the result's second half again to yield a 64 bit value.

This 64 bit value will of course never be able to represent all the possible values of the 256 bit hash either but it will not be possible to start with this value and calculate a collision for your original 256 bit hash.

Comment: Thank you Mr Linus Swälas for your help , so i will  try this method to get a short hash but can I get the same result with an other hash ?

Comment: Do you mean to use another hash, say MD5, to shrink your first result from 256 to 128 bits? If I understood correctly, my answer is, don't, using a second hash can only be weaker and never be stronger than using xor. Considering that you want a shorter hash, maybe cryptographic strength is not your primary concern though?

Comment: yeh i think so , i will lose the integrity. i explane my problem :
I want to generate a token for credit card number , i did a lot of research for that and i found many algorithm, this algo get a 16 char in entry and done a 16 alphanumeric char (this alpha numeric is unique) but I don't have the credit card number , i have the hash(sha256) of this number and i want to reduce this hash to represented it as a token .

Comment: @aia: You should edit your question to include a description of your problem.